# Plot with negative log scale in third quadrant

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to create plot like this with a semilog negative axis on the third quadrant. Is it possible?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel={Napätie \(U_D [V]\)},
        ylabel={Prúd \(I_D [A]\)},
        ymin=0, ymax=200,
        xmin=0, xmax=3.5,
    ]

    \addplot [
        domain=0:0.8, 
        samples=100, 
        color=blue,
    ]
    {5.8e-9*(e^((1.602e-19*x)/(1.38e-23*300))-1)};
    \addlegendentry{Si 300K}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Dioda}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

How can I add a semilog negative axis to this plot and place it to the third quadrant ?

Comment: You need separate overlapping axis environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Napätie \(U_D [V]\)},
        ylabel={Prúd \(I_D [A]\)},
        ymin=-100, ymax=200,
        ytick={0,50,100,150,200},
        xmin=-2, xmax=3.5,
    ]

    \addplot [
        domain=0:0.8, 
        samples=100, 
        color=blue,
    ]
    {5.8e-9*(exp((1.602e-19*x)/(1.38e-23*300)-1)};
    \addlegendentry{Si 300K}
    \coordinate (zero) at (axis cs: 3.5,0);
    \end{axis}%
    \path (zero);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xzero}{\yzero}%
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        scale only axis, width=\xzero, height=\yzero,
        axis x line=none, axis y line=box,
        xmin=-2, xmax=3.5,
        y dir=reverse,
        ymin=1.0e-50, ymax=1,
        ytick={1,1e-10,1e-20,1e-30,1e-40},
    ]
    \addplot[red,nomarks, domain=-2:0] {1.0e25^\x};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]